# Having issues with RPi zero 2w Not Booting

Tags: pi-zero-w-2

For the backstory, I recently bought a raspberry pi zero 2w for putting in a gameboy. This required soldering a dpi adapter from tinkerboy to all the gpio pins which for some reason did not work in the end. Long story short I was able to remove the adapter, but the pi was not booting.

After taking a break out of anger, I scrubbed down the pi with isopropyl alcohol which got it booting again. Even with booting it was very, very sluggish and would constantly freeze then unfreeze. After a significantly more thorough session of soaking the board in isopropyl alcohol for over 8 hours and intermittent scrubbing with a tooth brush, the pi was booting properly and not freezing anymore.

I believe what happened is that I used way, way too much Flux and it got everywhere on the board, including under the cpu which may have caused this behavior. I was able to install retropie, move emulators over to it through Filezilla and scrape games. Everything seemed to be working and it stayed on properly overnight.

Now the issue I'm having now is the board is randomly not booting at all. At first it stopped booting and would only boot with a fresh install of retropie on the sd card. Everytime I rebooted, it wouldn't boot anymore. The act led would come on for a second, then turn off and nothing would happen. After the board fails to boot, the power consumption drops to zero amps while still showing 5.2v on the test pads and gpio ports.

I've gone through a lot of time trying everything and looking all over the internet for some way to get it working. Plugging the rpi zero 2w into my computer still shows that the board pops up in my system devices indicating that it still works, yet doesn't boot. I've tried three different sd cards including a brand new one. After plugging and unplugging it over and over again the new sd card booted, got to the space resizing screen, rebooted, then failed to boot at all again.

I'm all out of ideas, with the polyfuse being my original theory of what isn't working until I learned that the rpi zero 2w doesn't have one. Is there anything else I can do to trouble shoot this thing?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: There is no 1 specific issue so I can't really do that. How can this problem possibly be diagnosed if I summarized it the way you want me to?

Answer (score 1):

Odds are YOU destroyed the Pi.

"I was able to remove the adapter" - removing a header, even for an experienced user with professional equipment is almost impossible without damage to the circuit board. (If there is ever a need to remove a header most would cut the plastic support and remove one pin at a time.)

"I used way, way too much Flux" what flux and WHY? There should be no need to use any flux for hand soldering through hole devices.

"soaking the board in isopropyl alcohol" is a BAD idea. You have likely ended up with gunk in places it shouldn't be.

Cut your losses and buy a new Pi. DON'T use flux but flux cored solder. After soldering examine (with a magnifying glass) to ensure there are no solder bridges BEFORE applying power.
Or better still buy a model with a professionally installed header.

Comment: Thank you for responding. In hindsight I 100% would have used a header but the maker of the dpi adapter specifically recommended soldering the boards together without a header to save space. I was able the get the boards separated with the only damage being two gpio port traces got destroyed but the solder itself just came apart without taking anything but the two traces with it. I used a microscope to inspect the board and there is no solder bridging anything together and the traces simply broke without taking anything else off the board.

Comment: I was also able to stress test the pi for a couple hours with heat and cpu speed benchmarks with nothing going wrong. I'm not doubting you that it's broken, but considering how the pi was able to boot, run at full speed during benchmarks, and play games without issues made me think something else is wrong. No other parts of the board got removed or damaged beside the two gpio traces and again there are no bridged connections.

Answer (score 0):

Try soldering 5V power supply onto GPIO +5V and GND pins. Maybe there is dirt on USB pins which can cause bad connection.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have at least a 2A power supply.  mine was doing everything you're describing until I did that.